# Excel Context Menu not working on one machine, but does on another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue in Excel 365, where any additional context menu items are not showing. This seems to be setting related rather than code-wise.

If I open the same workbook on a different (windows) machine, it works fine. Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere?

As an example, the following code works fine on one machine and not on the other, both created from scratch.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4375-excel-add-button-macro-to-right-click-menu.html

Thanks!

Comment: Does the code in discussion **run** on the machine where it does not return such a context menu? Is any VBA code running? And why "workbook related" if the same workbook works on a different computer?

Comment: Yes. Any other macro runs fine. Just the context menu ones don't seem to appear. Sorry, meant setting-related.